# Fullscreen browser script

Tags: javascript, browser, fullscreen

I have got a problem with my script making browser 's window to fullscreen. It's working for a single document ("document.body") but after click link to another site, browser closes fullscreen mode. Is it possible to change:

```
document.body
```

to something like this:

```
window.[...]
```

to make fullscreen mode pernamently like it is after press F11.

My script looking like that:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    // ## The below if statement seems to work better ##
    if((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (document.msfullscreenElement && document.msfullscreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
            if (document.body.requestFullScreen) {
                document.body.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } else if (document.body.msRequestFullscreen) {
                document.body.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```